# Implementing cart system using Multidimensional Associative php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am not getting the concept of two dimensional arrays in PHP. I am trying to implement a cart system in which an array Session variable store productid and the quantity of it.
For every new entry if it exists its quantity should be increased or if it does'nt then a new id should be added.
Here is my initial code.

```
function cart_increment_ajax($data, $qtt) {
    $_SESSION['count']+=$qtt;
    set_cart( $data );
    echo $_SESSION['count'];
}

function initialise_cart( ) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] =array( );
        $_SESSION['totalprice'] = 0;
}

function set_cart( $pid )  {
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        initialise_cart( );
                     }
        //else if( int $_SESSION['cart'] pid exists increment count ))
                    else
                    //     ($_SESSION['cart'] add new pid.

}
```

I am not getting how to implement the commented lines through Multidimensional associative array ?

Comment: ahh .. i forgot to write that line.

Comment: I want a session based cart .. you can use this simple class http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/21789.html

Comment: @Baba I am a beginner so i want to do it in noobest way. Its way too easy implementing the MD array in java. I am new to PHP, i mostly work in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small quick n dirty example of a multi-array in a session keeping a cart

```
<?php

function add_to_cart($product_id,$count)
{
    // no need for global $_SESSION is superglobal
    // init session variable cart
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    // check if product exists
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]))
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]=$count;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]+=$count;
}

// add some foos and a bar
add_to_cart('foo',2);
add_to_cart('foo',1);
add_to_cart('bar',1);

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
?>
```

This will produce

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 3
    [bar] => 1
)
```

HTH

Comment: I read this thing at many places. Why it is being called dirty.

Comment: By this thing I mean programming the cart using if else.

Comment: i call it quick-n-dirty because i wrote it fast in just a minute. i wouldn't call it rock solid :)

Comment: Never mind Sir ! I am learning things not implementing them in real projects right now.

Comment: this code works fine. can you guide me to some good article where i can understand this topic more precisely.

Answer (score -1):

Use the product ID as an index in your array, then simply increment it by using ++.

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$pid]++;
```

Comment: I am sorry. But wont that " ++ " increment the value at index.
I did this thing. I want to keep the $pid constant.

Comment: ehm, $arr[$pid++] is far away from $arr[$pid]++